# Run SCP From Command Line With Password

Tags: python, command-line, centos, fabric, scp

I need way to run SCP from the command line with a password.

Specifically, it's because I need to use the Python library Fabric to have one remote machine SCP to another remote machine, without the file passing through the local machine (it's a large file, and the two remote machines have a much quicker connection between each other than my local machine has with either of them.) The two remote machines are running CentOS.

But none of those details are particularly important with respect to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, elaborating on the security hazards of doing this, it's very easy to view command line arguments just by running `ps -ww -fp <pid>`. This vulnerability is why scp doesn't allow the password to be passed in on the command line.

So make sure that you're okay with the fact that anyone who can run that command could see the password in plain text.

The authors of SCP assume that you're so dumb that you would misuse the ability to pass in passwords on the command line. I, on the other hand, believe you've been warned adequately at this point, and if you want to do it, you shouldn't be stopped.

Onto the actual solution:

You need to install `expect` on the machine that should run SCP.

In my specific case of using the Python library Fabric to control a machine running CentOS, I ran the following to install it:

```
from fabric.operations import sudo

sudo('yum -y install expect')
```

To run it straight from the command line on CentOS, just do:

```
$ yum -y install expect
```

(I assume you know whatever your equivalent to yum is on your own OS.)

Once you have expect installed, you can run SCP like this:

```
expect -c
'spawn scp <copy-from-username>@<copy-from-address>:<copy-from-path> <copy-to-path>;
 expect "*?es??o*"   {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
        "*?assword:" {send "<copy-from-password>\r"};
 interact'
```

I've formatted it to make it easier to read, but you can replace the linebreaks/tabs with spaces and it'll work just the same.

The first line says that the following is an expect command (not the single quotes around the rest).

The second line spawns the SCP process.

The third line starts the definition of things to look for on the output and says that `"*?es??o*"` should get a response of `yes`. The `\r` is important for it to send the enter keystroke. The funky pattern is intended to catch something like `(Yes/No)`, as in, if it asks whether to proceed making a connection. `exp_continue` tells expect that it's not done after it replies to this message.

The fourth line has another thing to look for, the pattern in that line is intended to catch `Password:` regardless of if the p is capital or not. Make sure to include `\r` after the password or else it won't be sent. There's no `exp_continue` on this line because once expect has sent the password, we don't need it anymore.

The fifth line, `interact`, is important as this doesn't work without it. I'm a bit fuzzy on what exactly it does, but my understanding is that the `spawn` until that line is hit. I guess that's important because you need to define the expectations before spawn is run, or else the spawned process could pass whatever expect is supposed to look for, which could defeat the entire purpose. That's my understanding - I could be wrong. Either way, the script works.

Here's the Python function I wrote utilizing Fabric to do this in its entirety:

```
def putFromFileRepository(repoIP, repoUsername, repoPassword, repoPath, putPath):
    from fabric.operations import sudo

    # There are security implications from passing a password as an argument
    # on the command line, namely that command line arguments can be easily seen
    # from anywhere via 'ps -ww -fp <pid>'.
    # Thus scp doesn't allow passwords to be passed on the command line.
    # We'll install expect to make it possible.
    sudo('yum -y install expect')

    repoStr = repoUsername + '@' + repoIP + ':' + repoPath

    # expect has alien syntax - explained inline below.
    # see man expect for more details.
    sudo("expect -c 'spawn scp " + repoStr + ' ' + putPath + '; ' # Run SCP when started.
         + 'expect "*?es??o*" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue} '      # Reply yes to yes/no questions.
         + '"*?assword:" {send "' + repoPassword + '\r"}; '       # Give password when prompted.
         + "interact'")  # Start.
```